# How to control youtube embed live stream?

Tags: html, youtube, embed, live, autoplay

I have just learned that YouTube live stream URL is randomly changing. I found this on stackoverflow ["YouTube Live Streaming embed code keeps changing"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39204757/youtube-live-streaming-embed-code-keeps-changing)
so I know the the static embed link is this `https://www.youtube.com/embed/live_stream?channel=[channel ID]`

What I would like know is how to add `autoplay=1` to the embed link and any other functions like this.

**30/7/2017 Update** - this method does not work on ios V10.3.3 tested on an iPhone 6+ the player crashes safari and chrome !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's really simple, just add the parameter `autoplay=1` at the end:

`https://www.youtube.com/embed/live_stream?channel=[channel ID]&autoplay=1`

Comment: I have another question if the channel url is like this for example (www.youtube.com/user/france24english) how can i embed the static live stream ?

Comment: This by itself didn't work for me. Adding allow="autoplay" was necessary, as Havihavi says in another answer.

Answer (score 3):

allow autoplay and add it to the end of the embed src.

```
 <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ldy3VEPIRk0?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: For some reason autplay is not working on Firefox 82. On page load it simply doesn't start automatically.

Comment: The allow="autoplay" is important. That's what I was missing